# To evaluate $\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{\log(x)}{\sqrt x}$ using inequality

Tags: calculus, limits, logarithms, radicals

To evaluate $$\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{\log(x)}{\sqrt x}$$

I know that $\log(x) < x$ for $x > 0$. So dividing by square root of $x$ and taking limits gives me nothing. Which inequality should I use here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we substitute $t=\frac{1}{x}$ then
$$\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{\log(x)}{\sqrt x}=\lim_{t \to +\infty} {(-\sqrt{t}\cdot\log{t})} = -\infty$$
since $\log{t}>1$ for $t>e.$

Answer (score 3):

$$\lim_{x \to 0^+} \log(x)=-\infty$$
$$\lim_{x \to 0^+} \sqrt{x}=0^+$$
$$\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac {\log(x)}{\sqrt{x}} =-\infty$$
You don't need inequality here